# Network Connect Error with Java AutoViewer JNLP file

Tags: java, jnlp

I have an IPKVM that, when I try connect to a device, downloads a .jnlp file. Running that file always errors to "Network Connect Error." I was hoping someone could look their code over and tell me what I need to tweak or a if I need a different version of Java. Thanks in advance!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- JNLP File for Java Video Viewer Application -->

<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://192.168.2.28/webstart2">
   <information>
      <title>Video Session Viewer</title>
      <vendor>Avocent</vendor>
      <description>Video Session Viewer</description>
      <description kind="short">Video Viewer</description>
   </information>

   <security>
      <all-permissions />
   </security>

   <resources>
      <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" />
      <jar href="avctVideo.jar" main="true" />
      <property name="user.variant" value="avct" />
      <property name="oem.variant" value="avct" />
   </resources>
   <resources os="Windows">
     <nativelib href="acvvWin32Lib.jar" />
   </resources>
   <resources os="Linux">
     <nativelib href="libavctLinux.jar" />
   </resources>
   <resources os="SunOS">
     <nativelib href="libavctSolaris.jar" />
   </resources>

   <application-desc main-class="com.avocent.video.Nautilus">
      <argument>title="TempSense - Video Session Viewer"</argument>
      <argument>devicetype=avsp</argument>
      <argument>path=a:192.168.2.28,r:520430-073DA6,c:0,e:1,s:"TempSense",l:120</argument>
      <argument>oem=Avocent</argument>
      <argument>user=redacted</argument>
      <argument>password=redacted</argument>

   </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the vendor from "Avocent" to "Dell", add "avmWin32Lib.jar" for Windows resources (if you are using Windows), add "libavmLinux.jar"  (if you are using Linux):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- JNLP File for Java Video Viewer Application -->

<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://192.168.2.28/webstart2">
   <information>
      <title>Video Session Viewer</title>
      <vendor>Dell</vendor>
      <description>Video Session Viewer</description>
      <description kind="short">Video Viewer</description>
   </information>

   <security>
      <all-permissions />
   </security>

   <resources>
      <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" />
      <jar href="avctVideo.jar" main="true" />
      <property name="user.variant" value="avct" />
      <property name="oem.variant" value="avct" />
   </resources>
   <resources os="Windows">
     <nativelib href="acvvWin32Lib.jar" />
     <nativelib href="avmWin32Lib.jar" />
   </resources>
   <resources os="Linux">
     <nativelib href="libavctLinux.jar" />
     <nativelib href="libavmLinux.jar" />
   </resources>
   <resources os="SunOS">
     <nativelib href="libavctSolaris.jar" />
   </resources>

   <application-desc main-class="com.avocent.video.Nautilus">
      <argument>title="TempSense - Video Session Viewer"</argument>
      <argument>devicetype=avsp</argument>
      <argument>path=a:192.168.2.28,r:520430-073DA6,c:0,e:1,s:"TempSense",l:120</argument>
      <argument>oem=Dell</argument>
      <argument>user=redacted</argument>
      <argument>password=redacted</argument>

   </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

You could try only with the libraries at first and if does not work try all together.

Comment: Thanks, it works for me!!! I copied and paste the whole XML and change the path arg and main-class from the original XML and it works!!!

Comment: Awesome!!! My pleasure to know that this solve your issue @AdeelRizvi.